# Need help regarding Radeon graphic in Thinkbook 14-IML

Tags: lenovo, radeon, amd-graphics, gpu-driver, ubuntu-drivers

Here is my laptop spec:
https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=bfbf5b3302

Currently it's using MESA driver but seems not working.
Maybe somebody can help, please?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 0):

The amdgpu driver is not loaded and not available as graphics provider. Try to load it manually by modprobe after removing blacklisting from modprobe.d.